# Div with a gradient fill and: after

Tags: html, css, gradient

Faced with the problem of the gradient :after. 
How can I fill this construction gradient?
[My example in codepen.](http://codepen.io/volya/pen/BLAmvN)

```
<div class="text-uppercase top-winners">top winners</div>
.top-winners {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 120px;
  color: #141515;
  font-size: 33px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f3f0a0 0%, #efe93e 100%);
  border: none;
}

.top-winners:after {
  content: "";
  margin-left: 8px;
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid #f1e469;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
}
```

Comment: what are you looking for exactly?

Comment: @DivyanshuMaithani I'm looking for a way to fill this shape with a gradient